# How to push changes to a fetched and filtered Excel Table

Tags: excel, vba, search, filtering

For reference I have a similiar set up to: http://chandoo.org/wp/2012/11/27/extract-subset-of-data/.

So basically I have 3 sheets I'm working with. There's the RawData sheet which holds a table with you know the raw data. Then there's the master sheet which has the criteria that's going to be filtered and then a filter sheet which utilizes both to create a dropdown so that you can choose what you want to filter on the table and it's pulled to the filter sheet for viewing.

My question is thus: What direction would I be looking at so that if someone makes a change on the filter sheet it's then pushed to the rawdata sheet? I'm thinking something along the lines of

```
On worksheet change
    if target is not in row 1, 2, or 3,
        Search rawdata 'This is where I dont know exactly what I'd be doing 
        copy target row to rawdata row
```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest pushing changes based on an event. Users can play around with things and not want it to actually go anywhere. I would suggest making the changes based on a button click or something, so the user has to actively intend to commit the changes to the underlying data. But I don't know your model and so an event may be ok. Anyway, to answer your question: you will need to have a means of linking the changed row on the filter sheet back to the original. How? A unique ID? Revert back with more details please as it is a bit too generic at present to recommend an approach.

Comment: Also, just as an aside, I've never really understood the need for an approach (as effective as it is) like the one you linked to by chandoo.org. What is wrong with using the built-in filter data functionality to filter the data in place?

Comment: So for your aside, it's for the non-technical people. This way they can do an easy sort and get just the information they need since the spreadsheet itself is HUGE. It's purely for simplicity sake. So what I'm going for is the user will choose which operating system and then which application they want and it'll filter that out for them. (In the sheet both sets of data are in one column and the filter scroll is wicked tiny.) So for how I have it set up there's a section column and a subsection column (coulumn a and b respectively) which is unique enough to search for.

Comment: ok that makes sense. To commit the changes back you will need to either load the data necessary to uniquely identify the row from the destination worksheet into memory then search through it to find the target (v quick using a binary search, if sorted). Alternatively you can load and construct a hash table (keyed collection or dictionary object). Alternatively you can iterate through your filter rows and use an Excel Range.Search to find the target rows. This would be faster for a small number of rows to change, but slower for a large number.

Comment: Okay I'm going to start looking at the the last one (Excel Range.Search). If you're around and up to it before I report back can you post a sample of searching sheet1 for where column a matches $Target.Row$Column(1) AND column b matches $Target.Row$Column(2)? Thanks a bunch mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of examples of different methods below. You will of course need to change how it knows what the data range is and what keys to search on etc.

Once you have identified the relevant row, you can then make your changes to the data as required.

The below are based on some random letters in A1:B12, and it is desired to match on the combination of A and B.

```
'---Using Range.Find---
'The simplest method is to create a new column in Excel
'The column should use a formula to combine the different columns you want to match on together into a key
'An example would be, to match on column A and B: =A1 & "|" & B1
'You can then use Range.Search to find the match
Sub Example1()
    Dim searchRange As Range, matchedCell As Range

    Set searchRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("C")

    Set matchedCell = searchRange.Find( _
        what:="c" & "|" & "e", _
        LookIn:=XlFindLookIn.xlValues, _
        lookat:=XlLookAt.xlWhole, _
        MatchCase:=True)

    Debug.Print matchedCell.Address

End Sub

'---Using a keyed collection---
'This method is faster if you need to do the lookups a lot
'It does not need pre-generated keys in a column (unlike method 1)
'Though if you have pre-generated keys it can be optimised a bit by only loading
'the column of Keys into the array rather than all the data
Sub Example2()
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim arr
    Dim hashTable As Collection
    Dim i As Long

    Set dataRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B12")
    arr = dataRange.Value 'load the data into an array

    Set hashTable = New Collection

    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        hashTable.Add i, arr(i, 1) & "|" & arr(i, 2) 'add the row index as the value, and the key as the lookup conditions joined together
        'arr(i,1) etc will need to change depending on how you know which columns are the columns to match on
        'if datatype matters (i.e. "1" <> 1 for your lookup) then do something like
        'Vartype(arr(i,1)) & arr(i,1) & "|" & Vartype(arr(i,2)) & arr(i,2)
    Next i

    'Now for each match you need to do, you can just find the row within dataRange by looking up in the lookupCollection
    'e.g. to find "c|e":
    Debug.Print dataRange.Rows(hashTable("c" & "|" & "e")).Address

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm going to have to adjust it to make sure but this seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!